# Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. Nodejs / mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, nodes, node-mysql

I am having a few issues with one route that I am looking at...

```
app.get('/newusersvariables', function(req, res) {

const sessionid = req.session.id;


//let newuser = mysql.createConnection(mysqlconfig);
let connection = mysql.createConnection(mysqlconfig);

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM user_idpdetails WHERE sessionid = ?", [sessionid], function (err, result, fields) {     
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(result);
        connection.end();   
    });


});
```

I have tried moving around the connection.end but to no avail. In some situations, I get connection lost, as if it is ignoring the connection end. And if I move it to other places then I am getting

> 'Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.'

It is most likely something simple that I am overlooking as I am new to node.

Comment: This is just a guess (because there really isn't enough of your code to determine for sure), but you are most likely banging up against your connection limit in MySQL. Customarily, a single connection is created globally in a node app. Then that one connect is queried against. Here, you create a connect every time someone accesses that route - not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you! Based on this information I removed a redundant connection from the route and it has worked.

Comment: good to know. Glad to help!